# AlertDialog setcancelable (false) method

Tags: android

I have a problem to understand `setCancelable(false)` in android for `dialogBox`.

What does it actual mean and why should we use it? I am new to Android.

Comment: This is a Boolean for whether to close dialog on back press or not ..

Answer (score 7):

`setCancelable(false)` means that back key doesn't close the dialog.

If for example you want the dialog to be closed only if the user click some dialog button then both `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` and `setCancelable()` should be set to `false`

Answer (score 1):

`setCancelable(false)` means you cannot close the alert dialog after it's getting already opened 
For more informations :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html